# How to fade all body/document except this active tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple dropdown navigation. How can I fade the entire document when a list item is hovered in this case but still keep the list item and it is children at full opacity?

What can I add to this simple code?

```
$("#menu > li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show();
},function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to create an overlay `div` which has the same size as the current window, but a lower `z-index` than the element you want to remain highlighted (and by extension also higher than the rest of the document).

If you apply an opacity to that div then everything hidden underneath it will appear faded out.

e.g. (derived from jQuery UI's style sheets):

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=80); // for MSIE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you fade something out all it's child elements fade out as well, so you cannot do it the way you ask, i.e. fading out the body, as everything contained in the body will then be faded out!

Answer (score 0):

You should first select all the container elements, except the one your navigation is inside. Work with elements which are direct descendants of the body element. Do not select the body element itself.

Anyway, if you are using a list for navigation, you'll have to keep the whole menu opaque, otherwise you won't be able to do this.

To keep this as simple and fast as possible, try to keep your menu list as close as possible to the body element (ideal would be a child of body, without any further wrapping elements)

Give any elements an id or at least a class (for easier selection).

Then, select all the elements which are siblings of your menu

and fade them out.

Here is an example:

Let's have this page:

```
<body>
   <div id="header">This is a page head (logo, some widgets, slider, etc)</div>
   <div id="menuContainer">
      <ul id="menu">
         <li>menuitem</li>
         <li>menuitem</li>
         <li>menuitem</li>
         <li>menuitem</li>
         // .... as many items and levels you wish
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="contentContainer">
      you should have here the main content, sidebar, more widgets, whatever you like
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
      <div id="footer-1">
      </div>
      <div id="footer-2">
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Now the jquery part (the code may contain errors, it wasn't tested, it only shows, what should be done - and of course, it may be slow, depending of ho many nested elements do you have):

```
// recursive function for climbing in any multi level menu and hiding anything except the parents of our particular menu item. Anything below our menu item (it's children) are out of our scope, we won't have anything to do to them.
function fadeParents(item){
   var tmpParentUl = item.parents('ul')[0];
   var tmpParentUlLi = $(tmpParentUl).parents(li)[0];
   if (tmpParentUlLi){
     $(tmpParentUlLi).siblings('li').fadeOut();
     fadeParents($(tmpParentUlLi));
   }
}

$("#menu > li:has(ul)").hover(function(){
  // you may put all the elements in the same selection, i broke them apart just for the sake of this example
  // select all wrapper divs, except the one the menu is inside of and fade them out
  $("#header, #contentContainer, #footer").fadeOut(); // if you don't wish to animate, just hide();
  $(this).siblings('li').fadeOut();
  fadeParents($(this));
});
```

And to recover your elements in a visible state:

```
$('body *').fadeIn(); // or show();
```